# Tab bar disappears when returning from modal view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbar

I have a strange problem that I have not been able to resolve. I have a relatively large app with segues to modal view controllers from both UIViewControllers and UITableViewControllers. The UIViewControllers seem to work fine, however, I have an inconsistent problem with the table view controllers. The tab bar is displayed when I segue to the modal controller, and it displays correctly in the model view. However, when I dismiss the modal controller, there is a 50/50 chance that the tab bar on the table view controller will be  gone. The background view extends right to the bottom of the screen. The tab bar is translucent, so I want the background to extend behind it, but I have no idea why in some instances (with same controllers and same situation) work correctly and some don't. I haven't been able to find any pattern.

Before segue to modal:
[image]

Upon return from modal:
[image]

Initial tableview controller:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if optionEnabled[indexPath.row] {
        let segues:[String] = ["profileMenuSegue", "servicesProvidedSegue", "myWorkDaySegue", "myWorkWeekSegue", "timeOffSegue", "myAvailabilitySegue", "staffSegue", "promoSegue", "activateAccountSegue", "addWeekSegue"]

        performSegueWithIdentifier(segues[indexPath.row], sender: self)
    }

}
```

Modal view controller:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: params, encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL)
    .validate()
    .responseJSON { (request, _, result) in
        switch result {
        case .Success(let data):
            json = JSON(data)
            print(json)
            print("request successful")

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            })
        case .Failure(_, let error):
            print("request failed")
            print(error)
    }
}
```

I've tried all the "Extend Edges" settings both on and off, and I've tried overriding the "Inferred" for both top bar and bottom bar. I have presentation set to "Current Context" on all view controllers.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated, as I am running out of things to try.

Comment: Please post the relevant code

Comment: How are you dismissing the modal view controller?

Comment: I edited the original post to include both the calling and returning code.

Comment: @Lastmboy maybe instead of using dismissViewControllerAnimated just unwind segue

Comment: I switched several of the dismiss calls over to unwind segues and got excited, as I thought we had it, since it worked perfectly in the simulator. However, as soon as I put it on my iPhone it starting doing it periodically again.

Comment: Is there any way I can trace what is actually happening? e.g. whether view is in front of tab bar, or tab bar is not even there, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I could find that worked was to remove all modal segues. I switched them all over to "show" segues and haven't had a problem since. Must be something to do with the fact that I was not displaying the modal views full screen. I still had the tab bar on the bottom. When transitioning from the modal view back to the caller, there would often be a flash of colours at the tab bar, then sometimes the tab bar would come back, and other times it would be covered by the background.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and I fixed selecting "Over Current Context" on the presentation type of the segue. See image:

[image: Attribute inspector]

Comment: what a magical solution

Answer (score 0):

If I have your question right:
I had the same problem when I first started messing around with the tab bar controller! What I found is, if you segue back modally from a view controller, you have to segue all the way back to the tab bar controller. dismissViewController works better for me.

Comment: I should clarify. I was not "segueing back" to a previous controller. I was using dismissViewController, and later, unwind segues to return. However, just the fact that the original segue to the view controller was modal, causes the problem when dismissing it. I was forcing the modal view controllers to NOT be full screen (i.e. still show the tab bar). Now I'm using Show to get there and popViewController to get back, and everything is working fine.